# Rayleigh scattering and dimension of oscillator compared to wavelenght

Tags: electromagnetism, scattering, diffusion

Why is Rayleigh scattering suitable only for cases where the oscillator dimensions are much smaller than incindent wavelenght?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the *definition* of Rayleigh scattering: it's what happens when you scatter light (or other EM waves) off of particles whose size is much smaller than the wavelegth. If you have particles that are comparable to or bigger than the wavelength, then you get [Mie scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering).